# Recovering files on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, data-recovery, deleted-files

I would like to know if it is possible to recover files that I have deleted?

I have VPS with CentOS 7 and if it is possible I would like to look for (and recover) deleted files by their file extensions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had pretty good success with TestDisk & PhotoRec for recovering deleted files. Haven't tried it via an SSH session but make sure you install and run screen command. I've had recovery scan that last over 24 hours.

Comment: I have used testdisk and had a great success. I didn't have a long scan. Probably cause of two reasons. First is that that VPS is pretty much new and doesn't have a lot of stuff. And second reason is cause I knew in which directory those files were, so I have pinpointed a scan on that directory.